# How can I go through a 2D Array via the secondary diagonal?

Tags: java, c++, multidimensional-array, diagonal

As I said, I would like to "scroll" through a Multi Dimensional array via the secondary diagonal, my desired input to be: (Case a) [It can be in either C++ or Java, it doesn't matter]

NOTE+EDIT: The order is not random. It starts from the 1 at the bottom and goes its way up.

Is this possible?

If not then at least half of the code? (Case b)

```
// Case a:
16 15 13 10
14 12 9 6
11 8 5 3
7 4 2 1

// Case b:
0 0 0 1
0 0 9 6
0 8 5 3
7 4 2 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple loop (this is Java):

```
int size = 4;
int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];
// . . .
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    doSomethingWith(matrix[i][size - i - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  int[][] a={{7,6,4,1},{5,3,9,6},{2,8,5,3},{7,4,2,1}};
  for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
  {
   for(int j=a[i].length-1; j>=a[i].length-(i+1); j--)
   {
    System.out.print(a[i][j]+",");
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
```